# Shopify - Conditionally using variant image as thumbnail if available

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there a way to use variant image as thumbnail if available? For example, I have a product that comes in Black, Blue and Red, and successfully associate them with specific image. How do i get those images as list item and using just standard featured image if color variant isn't available? Here's the scenario for help:

```
{% if variant color is available %}
    <ul class="variantimage-on">
        <li>Black Image</li>
        <li>Blue Image</li>
        <li>Red Image</li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul class="variantimage-off">
        <li><img src="{{ product.images.first | product_img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}" /></li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You mean if it's selected? Or just if it's available you show the image, and if it's not, you hide it?

Comment: I want to show variant image only if product contains color variant, otherwise it shows default featured image.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
{% if product.options contains 'Color' %}
    <ul class="variantimage-on">
       {% for image in product.images %}
           {% for variant in image.variants %}
               <li><img src="{{variant.image.src | img_url: 'large'}}"
                        alt="{{variant.title}}"/></li>
           {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

If all your variant titles start with the color name, you could do a sort by title (group by color) then iteration with a "if new color". Replace the innermost for loop by this:

```
{% assign variants = image.variants | sort: 'title' %}
{% assign color = "" %}
{% for variant in variants %}
    {% assign words = variant.title | split: ' ' %}
    {% if color != words[0] | downcase %}
         {% assign color = words[0] | downcase %}
         <li><img src="{{variant.image.src | img_url: 'large'}}"
                  alt="{{variant.title}}"/></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{image.src}}` doesn't returns to full image url but replacing it with `{{ variant.image.src | img_url: 'large' }}` fixes the issue. Another issue is that I have 2 variant options (Color & Size), right now it's looping through and displaying every single variant. For instance, Red 4' x 6', blue 4' x 8' etc. How to avoid duplicate colors,and only loop through the color option?

Comment: Updated code. An `if` statement on `variant.option1` and `variant.option2` will always be the same through `variant` iteration

Comment: What about doing something with `{% if variant.title contains "..." %}` ?

Comment: I added some code for an idea on how to select by color.